# Why the shell doesn't write the good hour and give me the year?

Tags: shell, command-line, hour

I'm a little bit confused, i changed my time on one file with the shell command :

- touch -t = ***touch -t 201606012135 trial01***

But after the ***ls -lt***, I got this :

```
  -rw-r--r--   1 CharleyD  staff       87  1 jun  2016 trial01
  drwxr-xr-x  15 CharleyD  staff      510  3 apr 12:57 Hybrid_proj
```

Why the shell doesn't write the hours like the "Hybrid_proj" directory for the "trial01" ? The trial01 file have the hour : 21:35, so itsn't empty.

Indeed, I search to get this in output :

```
-rw-r--r--   1 CharleyD  staff       87  1 jun 21:35 trial01
drwxr-xr-x  15 CharleyD  staff      510  3 apr 12:57 Hybrid_proj
```

How I can do this ?

Thx a lot buddies to enlighten my way ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a file is not from the current year, `ls` defaults to showing the year instead of the time. The time is still correctly set, just formatted differently.

To always show the full time, with GNU `ls`, you can use `ls --time-style=long-iso -l`:

```
$ ls --time-style=full-iso -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2017-04-04 13:20 newfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2016-04-03 12:34 oldfile
```

With BusyBox `ls`, you can use `-e`:

```
$ busybox ls -e
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 user    user            0 Tue Apr  4 13:20:42 2017 newfile
-rw-r--r--    1 user    user            0 Sun Apr  3 12:34:00 2016 oldfile
```

With macOS `ls`, you can use `-lT`:

```
$ ls -lT 
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 user  group  0 Apr  4 13:19:35 2017 myfile
-rw-r--r--  1 user  group  0 Apr  3 12:34:00 2016 oldfile
```

In each case, you get a long timestamp with the same format for older and newer files.

Comment: Oooh ! That's why !  Thx for your explanation so helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-T` option if your `ls` supports it.